# Unexpected namespace prefix “custom” found for tag fragment while trying to use custom attributes

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, android-custom-attributes

I am following this [android developer page](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html) for the creation of custom attributes for an app. Everything is going fine and **I am able to compile and see the results also**.
But the part which is giving issue is IDE.Android Studio is complaining for unexpected namespace custom. Is there any way to disable/hide this error message? This is very annoying.

Even with this error, however, I am able to compile and run the app.

[image]

I followed follwing steps.

1) Created res/values/attrs.xml file and added

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <resources>
<declare-styleable name="FragArguments">
    <attr name="max_allowed" format="integer"/>
    <attr name="header" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

2) Trying to use in my mainlayout file's fragment tag

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res"
                          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                          android:layout_height="0dip"
                          android:layout_weight="1">
                <fragment android:id="@+id/msg"
                          android:name="org.android.fragment.MessageFragment"
                          custom:max_allowed="85"
                          custom:header="@string/header"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

3. Applying the custom attributes through code overriding the onInflate() method of fragment

```
   @Override
    public void onInflate(Activity activity, AttributeSet attrs, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onInflate(activity, attrs, savedInstanceState);

        TypedArray typedArray = activity.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FragArguments);
        max_allowed = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.FragArguments_max_allowed, -1);
        header = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.FragArguments_header);
        typedArray.recycle();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just figured out the solution.

The **issue ID MissingPrefix** tells lint to only scan for XML attributes that are missing the Android namespace prefix.So we can do this two ways:--

1. Canissue the following command to scan the files under the main project directory and its subdirectories.

> lint --check MissingPrefix myproject

2. In android studio create a lint.xml file with following content and add in app directory.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <lint>
>     <issue id="MissingPrefix" severity="ignore"/>
> </lint>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Nicks answer. You can also add following lines to the build.gradle file, inside android {} scope:

```
    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingPrefix'
    }
```